# Перегрузка операторов вне и внутри класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, перегрузка-операторов

В ТЗ моей работы указано, что перегрузка операторов должна выполняться как вне, так и внутри класса.

Я не совсем понимаю как это работает и хотел попросить Вашего совета.
В моем понимании перегрузка оператора внутри класса - это:

```
class foo {
public:
  foo();
  foo operator + (foo arg);
}
```

Тогда как быть с выполнением вне класса..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас —

```
class foo{
public:
  foo();
  foo operator + (const foo& arg);
}
```

оператор объявлен в классе, как функция-член класса. Но его можно объявить и вне класса, как свободную функцию, просто записав его с двумя аргументами:

```
foo operator+(const foo& arg1, const foo& arg2) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: только я не совсем понял _ все таки void foo() здесь никакой не класс, а функция. Не  проясните о чем речь?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Слона-то я и не приметил... :) Сосредотачиваешься на задаче, код копируешь не глядя. Поскольку в условии "вне и внутри класса", я даже не глянул на первую строку.

Спасибо, что указали...

Comment: Скорее всего моя ошибка =)